# Build docker go application with command to lint

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I've created the following docker container , all works except on thing which is the make lint

In the project root I've `Makefile` with the current entry

```
lint:
    gometalinter --config=gometalinter.json ./...
```

when I use it locally in my machine (macbook) and if for example file is not formatted `go fmt` I get error when executing above code.

The problem is that when I create the docker image via `docker build command`

I got different linting issues which is not related to my project.
in the `gometalinter.json` I've the following entry to bypass the vendor directory

```
{
  "vendor": true
}
```

This is the docker content

```
FROM golang:1.11.1-alpine3.7 

RUN apk add --update --no-cache git make curl bash

ADD https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.5.0/dep-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/dep
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/dep

WORKDIR /go/src/my-proj

COPY . ./

COPY Gopkg.toml Gopkg.lock ./

RUN dep ensure 
# From the error it seems that this is related to cgo but even adding the next line doesnt helps, same error occurred 
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0
# this command download gometalinter which is running OK
RUN make download 

RUN make lint
```

when I run the lint this is what I got which is not related to my project

```
../../../usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:80:24:warning: error return value not checked (undeclared name: cgoLookupHost) (errcheck)
../../../usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:95:24:warning: error return value not checked (undeclared name: cgoLookupIP) (errcheck)
../../../usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:107:23:warning: error return value not checked (undeclared name: cgoLookupPort) (errcheck)
../../../usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:123:24:warning: error return value not checked (undeclared name: cgoLookupCNAME) (errcheck)
../../../usr/local/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:323:23:warning: error return value not checked (undeclared name: cgoLookupPTR) (errcheck)
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable _CGO_ by setting `CGO_ENABLED` environment variable to `0` (zero)?

Comment: @Alirus - yes I did it and it doesnt work, same error

Comment: Maybe, and just maybe, you're not doing it right. Try to prepend it to the `make lint` command, such as `RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 && make lint`, and see the result.

Comment: @Alirus - Ok I will try it now

Comment: @Alirus - Thanks, I try that either and same erorr I got , any other hint pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly setting the [environment variable in your Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

`RUN CGO_ENABLED=0`

should be

`ENV CGO_ENABLED=0`